# Can my non-Jewish co-worker bring me coffee from the corner cafe?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, gentiles, employment

[Assuming coffee is Kosher](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/19088/5), would it be alright if my non-Jewish co-worker brings me coffee on a trip to the corner cafe?  May I assume that the co-worker indeed purchased a Kosher item and has not adulterated it in any way?

Comment: This site makes no guarantee of validity, and does not offer professional (particularly rabbinic) advice. Treat information from this site like it came from a crowd of your friends.

Comment: What @msh210 said. First person singular in the question is meant to be read as a narrative to make the question sound more imminent. I did not wrestle with this question at work this morning on a personal level.

Answer (score 4):

Foods sent via a non-Jewish courier and not sealed are forbidden to the (Jewish) recipient, as a precaution in case the courier switched the kosher food sent with non-kosher food he picked up along the way. However, most *pos'kim* hold that where there is no incentive for the courier to switch the food, there is no concern; moreover, if there is no opportunity for him to do so, there is no concern. So if there is a cheaper non-kosher source of coffee in the neighborhood (incentive and opportunity to switch), the route the courier is taking is not heavily populated (opportunity to switch, as no one will see him do so and report it to you), and the lid is not tamper-evident or is easily replaced with another (no seal), then the coffee would, it seems to me, be forbidden to you; otherwise, it seems to me the coffee would be permitted to you.

But consult your rabbi for practical *halacha*.

Source: [*Halachically Speaking*](http://www.shemayisrael.com/parsha/halacha/), volume 6, issue 6 (which cites further sources).

Comment: This answer is assuming that the corner coffeeshop is kosher but another source of coffee might not be.

Comment: that doesn't seem a great assumption.  Perhaps if you asked for Chalav Yisrael milk in your coffee and there is another coffee shop with Chalav Stam milk.