# Are Dunkin Donuts Coolatas kosher?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, restaurant, modern-times

For the purposes of this discussion, let's assume that unflavored coffee with milk is kosher everywhere you go. ([Related MY question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/19088/5323))

**Are [Coolata](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coolatta)s (from [Dunkin Donuts](https://www.dunkindonuts.com/content/dunkindonuts/en.html)) included in this?**

A friend of mine went to a Dunkin Donuts and bought a Coolata, and a different friend asked him, with a look of amazement on his face, "You mean you can buy  Coolata's at *trief* Dunkin Donuts!?"

Thought I'd ask if any kashrus organizations wrote anything on the topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The CRC says](http://www.crcweb.org/beverage_list.php):

> Coolata (Dunkin Donuts): Not all are certified kosher. Only recommended when purchased from a kosher certified location.

I would read that as saying it depends on the flavor, primarily.

Comment: +1.....any info on how to tell which are certified kosher?

Comment: @Shokhet, I don't know, but I would guess you have to ask to look at the package it came in. At least that is how it works with similar products in such a situation.

Comment: @Shokhet "Only recommended when purchased from a kosher certified location."